# How can I find what row isn't allowing the column conversion to float/int in Python?

Tags: python

so I have a dataframe with 300 thousand rows, 12 columns, including one column called value. Basically all the values in this column are of a type that can be converted to float, except for a row or two which includes the headers, which find their way in there as a result of the consolidation process. How can I find this troublesome row?

Thank you!

Comment: `df[~df['col'].str.matches("\d+\.?\d*")]` ... maybe ... its hard to say without some example

Comment: Hello, so the header is value, id, date. For some reason, a row of these headers sneaks into the dataframe as string. So 'value' in the value column, 'date' in the date column and 'id' in the id column.